# creating custom onError and onLoad Methods in Java

Tags: java

I have been working on my own Http Client Class, and i want a way to implement the onload and oerror feature like, "declaring an event and actions for that event", if an error with the connection happened i must have the ability to specify a custom action for it.

```
public static void Error(int code){
  System.out.println("Oops, something went wrong Error code:" + code.toString());
}

URL url = new URL("http://example.com/");

Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("key","value");
http_client client = new http_client(url, "GET", params , true);

client.onError = Error(client.ErrorCode);
```

Something like that.

Here is my class:

```
class http_client {

    protected String responseText;
    protected boolean loaded = false; 
    protected boolean error = false;

    public http_client(URL url, String method , Map<String,String> parameters , boolean cache) throws IOException, ProtocolException{

      HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

      int status = connection.getResponseCode();

      if(status > 299){
        error = true;
      }

      connection.setRequestMethod(method);

      if(method == "POST"){
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      }

      connection.setUseCaches(cache);

      connection.setDoInput(true);
      connection.setDoOutput(true);

      DataOutputStream s = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

      s.writeBytes(paramToStr(parameters));
      s.flush();
      s.close();


      InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

      StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
      String CurrentLine;

      int lines = 0;

      while((CurrentLine = reader.readLine()) != null){
        lines += 1;
        response.append(CurrentLine + "\n");
      }

      reader.close();

      responseText = response.toString();
      responseText = responseText.substring(0 , responseText.length() - 1);

      if(lines == 1){
        responseText = responseText.replace("\n","");
      }

      loaded = true;


    }

    public static String paramToStr(Map<String, String> parameters) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{

      StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(); 
      result.append("?");

      for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry: parameters.entrySet()){

          String key = URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey() , "UTF-8");
          String value = URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue() , "UTF-8");

          result.append(key);
          result.append("=");
          result.append(value);
          result.append("&");
      }

      String str = result.toString();
      str = result.substring(0 , str.length() - 1);
      return str;
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to use Pattern Strategy in Java

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Function` Interface Java provides:

```
class http_client {
  protected String responseText;
  protected boolean loaded = false;
  protected Function<Integer, Void> success;
  protected Function<Integer, Void> error;

public http_client(URL url, String method , Map<String,String> parameters , boolean cache, Function<Integer, String>success, Function<Integer, String> error) throws IOException, ProtocolException{

    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    int status = connection.getResponseCode();

    if(status > 299){
      error.apply(status);
    } else {
      success.apply(status);
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

to call it just pass some lambda function

```
...
http_client client = new http_client(url, "GET", params , true, status -> System.out.println("success! " + status), status -> System.out.println("error " + status));
```